# How do I recover my Angry Birds progress!

Tags: cyanogenmod, data-recovery, angry-birds

I'm using Cyanogen and had some issues so in recovery I had to "wipe data". Before I did that I did a backup. How can I get back my Angry Birds save data? I thought for sure it was stored on Google's servers since I've done this sort of thing 50 times before and never lost my save games.

Comment: What do you mean by you did a backup? Titanium Backup?

Comment: I made a backup in "recovery" when you power on and press the ball at the same time. Everything is stored in .img files I guess because that's what I see in the File Manager.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angry Birds save data is stored to `/data/data/com.rovio.angrybirds/files`.  I don't believe it's backed up to Google.  Normally all that's backed up is your list of apps, certain settings, contacts, etc.  So your `wipe data` would have erased it.

I always use [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to save my apps and their data.  And when I do something risky like flash a beta ROM that might wipe the phone storage, I back up Titanium's backup folder to my PC.

Comment: I have a backup that was made in recovery but they are all .img files. Maybe I should be asking how to extract data from there. Also, where on the SD card is the savefile stored??

Comment: One thing you could do is restore the backup, you should be able to do this in recovery.  Then back up Angry Birds with Titanium, move that backup to your PC, wipe data again, copy back the Angry Birds backup, and restore it with Titanium.  Mounting the .img files is somewhat complicated, you have to set up a loopback device and stuff.  I wouldn't recommend that unless you're very comfortable with the command line and such.

Comment: Okay, I'm about to do a Restore with ROM Manager but I don't think those are the right ones. Might have to boot to recovery again and restore from there. ARG! I thought I read Google has a cool "cloud backup" for Android Apps. Must not be that cool.

Comment: I did the restore and I don't see any data/data folder. There is other things in data but mostly related to twitter stuff. I'm scared. Now going to a backup from January . . . it'll be old be better than starting from scratch. Gotta backup more often but I was running out of room on my SD card.

Comment: Okay, I'm all the way back to January and I Angry Birds is even installed on this version and it launches and my old data is there . . . but I still can't find it. Not in sdcard/data/data

Comment: Make sure you're looking on the phone storage, not the SD card.  Only the app should be on the SD card, the save files are on the phone storage.  You need root to browse /data/data (I assume you have it though, being on CM)

Comment: Okay, looking at other questions it turns out "File Manager" lies. There ARE folders in the /data/data folder on the phone but sadly, no angry birds.